# Migrating Azure Service Bus Queue to Topic and Subscription

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

We have created Azure service bus queue and have a azure function - servicebus queue trigger subscribed to it. We now want this queue to convert to Topic as we will need multiple subscription to it. is there a way that we can convert queue to Topic without deleting queue and re creating this as a Topic. I understand that Azure function code which is in c# needs to be changed so it points to service bus topic.

Thanks,
Punit Singhi

Answer (score 1):

Use the **ForwardTo** feature for forwarding a message to the topic entity.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: Queues can have an auto-forwarding set. It will cause messages to be forwarded to the destination (another queue or topic) on the broker side. That way there's no need to make any changes to the senders and those can continue using the queue. There's an [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding) on the topic.